# Response message after submit button

Tags: submit

```
<form action="http://sms.services/send-sms" method="get">
    <input type="number" name="to" />
    <input type="text" name="message" />

    <input type="hidden" name="app-id" value="108744" />
    <input type="hidden" name="password" value="1111111" />
    <input type="hidden" name="from" value="TestSender" />

    <input type="submit" value="Submit" />
</form>
```

Hi!
I am trying to display a page with a message like "Message send successfully" when the submit button is clicked. Any ideas?

Thanks in advance

Comment: do you know about ajax?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using PHP
 1. create a thank you page.
 2. add php code if submit button was clicked that redirects to thank you page Example:

```
<?php
if(isset($_POST['submit'])){
header("Location: thank_you.php");
}
?>
```